# How can I access a JMS queue from a Java class using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I have an Apache Camel middleware to sync entities between two systems. In case of an error when the entity reaches its destination I store a message in a JMS queue with info about that error.

We also have an API inside Camel to 'query' that queue. One of the GET methods of said API should bring all messages in the error queue and form a response for using EntityId + error message for each message in the queue.

I know that I can consume from a queue using something like this (I'm using Spring Boot) :

```
@Autowired
private ConsumerTemplate consumTemplate;
```

And then call `receive` from that `ConsumerTemplate`, but that doesn't seem  to be a very appropriate way to doing it because how can I know when there are no more messages? I can wait for a `null`, but I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

So my question is: is there some way to get all the messages from a queue into a `List` or something like that as opposed to consuming them one by one? And I will also need to not 'consume' them but rather browse them, so all messages remain in the queue for further processing.

I tried with something like this:

```java
@Autowired
private JmsComponent jms;

public void getAllErrorGroups() throws Exception {
    javax.jms.Session jmsSession = jms.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    QueueBrowser browser = jmsSession.createBrowser(jmsSession.createQueue(ApplicationConstants.Routes.ERROR _QUEUE_ROUTE));        
    Enumeration<?> enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
}
```

But I got nothing on `enumeration`. I looked at it in the debugger, and also did a `while(enumeration.hasNext())` and it never entered the `while` loop.

Comment: To get all the messages from a queue into a List or something like that. As opposed to consume the messages one by one. And I can wait for a null, I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

The JMS API doesn't support the ability to receive more than one message at a time so you'll have to go one-by-one. Also, I don't know of any more elegant way to determine a queue is empty than invoking `receive(long)` with a timeout and getting `null`.

As for your browser, I believe you're not getting anything because you haven't invoked `start()` on your JMS connection. Try something like this:

```java
@Autowired
private JmsComponent jms;

public void getAllErrorGroups() throws Exception {
   javax.jms.Connection jmsConnection = jms.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
   javax.jms.Session jmsSession = jmsConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   jmsConnection.start();

   QueueBrowser browser = jmsSession.createBrowser(jmsSession.createQueue(ApplicationConstants.Routes.ERROR _QUEUE_ROUTE));
    
   Enumeration<?> enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
}
```

Comment: It's still empty sadly :(

Comment: I looked at the debugger, and also did a while(enumeration.hasNext()) and it never entered that while.

Comment: Did you confirm that corresponding JMS queue has messages in it? If so, how?

Comment: In my test case I send a message to the queue before I call the getAllErrorGroups() function. And I can also see that error on the ActiveMQ UI.

Comment: Are you sure `ApplicationConstants.Routes.ERROR _QUEUE_ROUTE` refers to the proper queue at the broker? If you stop your application in the debugger when `getEnumeration` is called on `browser` does the ActiveMQ web console show your client?